# Should I rent a virtual Mac for Flutter development?

Tags: xcode, firebase, android-studio, flutter, virtual-machine

I'm going to begin working on cross-developing an app for iOS and Android using Flutter.  I have a Windows computer and use Android Studio for mobile development (new to Flutter, but have experience with Android development).

I am going to need to use a Mac at the very least to set up Firebase dependencies in the app, but it is unclear to me how much time I will actually need access to a Mac.  I don't want to overpay.

When developing an app with Flutter, do I always need to use XCode to test run the app on an iOS device, even if I have a physical iPod in front of me?  For instance, I can use my Android phone with USB debugging to run/test the app on my phone thru Android Studio.  Can I do the same thing with an iPod and Android Studio, or does it have to be done through XCode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good PC/Laptop with good resources you can use VM Box and install macOS in it. After that you can use it to testing for iOS purposes.

Considering a rent on MAC is probably isn't a good option.

Comment: Is it relatively difficult to set that sort of thing up?  I have a bad track record with messing up installations, I don't want to brick my computer.

Comment: @MilesZoltak You download a hypervisor like VM Box or VMWare, get a MacOS ISO, then just install the OS into a virtual machine like you would a real computer. If you mess anything up, you can just delete the virtual machine and try again. I've never set up a Mac VM before, but for Linux and Windows systems it's trivial.

Answer (score -1):

Renting will cost alot and will even go over budget if time is not spent properly. Therefore, in my opinion it would be best to get an old mac mini and maybe upgrade it if you have the budget

Comment: I actually do have an old Mac Mini i can use, but if it is quite old will that be a problem with downloading a usable version of XCode (in terms of OS compatibility) and testing?

Comment: If local is an option, I would think that it'd be cheaper to buy a VMware license then just run it in there.

Comment: You can use VM with macOS

Comment: using vm to run MacOS totally depends on the specs your current pc has